# Executing javascript in python results in KeyError

Tags: javascript, python, string, selenium, formatting

I'm having a hard time while trying to execute script in python selenium... I'm trying to check if certain element is in specified parent, and if it is, it should return true.

Here is my code:

```
    for box in range(len(browser.find_elements(*selector))):

    result = browser.execute_script("""
    var nodesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".o-boxes__item"));
    if(document.querySelector("div:nth-child({}) > div > div.m-package-box__body > div:nth-child(10) > div > label") === nodesArray[{}]){
        false
    }else{
        nodesArray[{}].contains(document.querySelector("div:nth-child({}) > div > div.m-package-box__body > div:nth-child(10) > div > label"));
    }""".format(box+1, box, box, box+1))
    print(str(result))
```

and when I run it, it gives me this output in console:

```
nodesArray[{}].contains(document.querySelector("div:nth-child({}) > div > div.m-package-box__body > div:nth-child(10) > div > label"));
>           }""".format(box+1, box, box, box+1))
E           KeyError: '\n            false\n        '

tests/test_shopEshop.py:111: KeyError
```

I don't know what else I could do... I've tried to change the code in execute_script part, tried to change the string formatting (f formating, .format method, hard coded parameters) but nothing works and I'm starting to give up...

Comment: Why are you doing so much in JS when you are using python? You should be able to do all this using just python. It would be better if you would post the relevant HTML (as text) so we can determine if your locator is correct/optimal and then maybe determine a better approach.

Comment: The issue is with `box+1`. On the last loop box+1 is greater than the range length.

Comment: You could start by replacing the variable `nodesArray` with something like `find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='o-boxes__item']")`. And if you could get us even just a copy paste of the html that would help. `driver.page_source` will return the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

@Jortega here is my whole test

```
    def test_package_box_href(browser, base_url, testrail_data_file, commentary):
    '''
        Sprawdza czy atrybut href w button w package boxie zgadza
        się z adresem URL do którego prowadzi oraz przy zmianach zaznaczonego toggle
    '''
    Menu(browser).go_to_page(Menu(browser).SHOP, Menu(browser).SHOP_SHOP)
    page_old = GenericTemplateOld(browser)

    testrail = ApiTestrailRequest(testrail_data_file["run_id"], '32252')
    verification = Assertions(browser, testrail_data_file, commentary)

    selector = page_old.PACKAGE_BOXES_BUTTON

    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
            EC.url_to_be(base_url + '/sklepy-internetowe/')
        )

    for box in range(len(browser.find_elements(*selector))):

        print(len(browser.find_elements(*selector)))
        script ="""
        var nodesArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".o-boxes__item"));

        if(document.querySelector("div:nth-child({}) > div > div.m-package-box__body > div:nth-child(10) > div > label") === nodesArray[{}]){
            return false;
        }else{
            return nodesArray[{}].contains(document.querySelector("div:nth-child({}) > div > div.m-package-box__body > div:nth-child(10) > div > label"));
        }
        """.format(1,0,0,1)
```

E           KeyError: '\n            return false;\n        '

Answer (score 0):

i had similar issue i removed .format()  and resorted to  old school % formatting,
like so

```
stuff_in_string = "Shepherd %s is %d years old." % (shepherd, age)

print(stuff_in_string)
```

hope this helps in your case, i believe .format looks for {} brackets and that cause it to consider anything inside it as variable